# PythonをCGIとして実行する際、実行ファイルの絶対パスを自動で取得したい

Tags: python, python3

**最終的にやりたいこと**

> https://example.com/questions/ask/index.py

上記実行する際、index.pyページ上で、「/questions/ask/index.py」を自動で取得したい

---

**現状**
・フルパスを取得後、「var/www/example.com」を手動で書いて削除しました

---

Q1.「var/www/example.com」をPythonで取得するには？
・この部分をコードに直書せず自動で取得したい

---

Q2.[urllib](https://docs.python.jp/3/howto/urllib2.html)で出来そうに思ったのですが、urlをコードに直書している例が掲載されています
・スクリプト実行している現在URLは取得できない？？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

環境変数に実行環境に応じた値が入っているはずなので、この中から必要なキーを参照すれば良さそうです。

```py
import os

os.environ['SERVER_NAME']     # example.com
os.environ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']   # /var/www/
os.environ['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] # /var/www/questions/ask/index.py
os.environ['SCRIPT_NAME']     # /questions/ask/index.py
```